# Is there a good, clean way to pit black olives?

Tags: olive

I wanted to pit a black olive, like a Kalamata, and retain the shape - is there a good clean way to take the pit out?

Answer (score 7):

Two Options which work for both olives and cherries:

1. Use a drinking straw and push through one end until you hit the pit and keep pushing until the pit comes out.
2. Use a large paper clip partially opened so that the end can be used for inserting and pushing the pit through.

Answer (score 1):

i've heard that cherry pitters work. (like this one: http://tinyurl.com/37rzuab)